# How to get an "extern const int" value by its name

Tags: ios, objective-c, reflection

I would like to get the `int` value of my `extern const` by its name.

For example in my .h file:

```
extern const int MY_INT_CONST;
```

In my .m file:

```
const int MY_INT_CONST = 0;
```

What I want:

```
- (void) method {
    int i = [getMyConstantFromString:@"MY_INT_CONST"];
}
```

How can I do that?

I searched in RunTime api and I did not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple way to do this. Neither the language nor the runtime provide a facility for this.

It can be done using the API of the dynamic loader to look up a symbol's address by its name.

```
// Near top of file
#include <dlfcn.h>

// elsewhere
int* pointer = dlsym(RTLD_SELF, "MY_INT_CONST");
if (pointer)
{
    int value = *pointer;
    // use value...
}
```

Note, that's a C-style string that's passed to `dlsym()`. If you have an `NSString`, you can use `-UTF8String` to get a C-style string.

Comment: This works really great ! Tank you for your answer, you made my day

Answer (score 0):

No need for [getMyConstantFromString:@"MY_INT_CONST"];

directly use as follows

```
- (void) method {
    int i = MY_INT_CONST;
}
```

Comment: But where I want to get my constant value, the only information I have is its name. Is there any way to do it by reflection ? I have no other choice to use reflection in my context.

Comment: I am not sure but reflection is possible only for classes.